# Can't take a screenshot of entire div element (scroll chat div)

Tags: html, css, firefox

There is a div. In this div has a chat. This div has scroll bar. I want to take a screenshot of all this div content at once. I almost did it by changing the div height to 500% and overflow: visible, but I got a problem. In fact I got about a large part of the chat in the screenshot, but at some point the chat just disappeared with a long white space till the end of the image as shown below.

I took this screenshot using the Firefox's "Screenshot node" feature. And I tried all possible extensions you can imagine before it and none worked (they don't detect the div scroll, just the main page scroll). Anyways, I want a HTML/CSS solution if possible. I want to understand why it is not working.

[image: The screenshot of chat div]

As you can see, there a lot of white space, but there is a lot of more chat that was ignored by the print.

What could have happened?

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla-services/screenshots/issues/2129), they do/did limit screenshots to 5000px. You might want to open a new issue on their github page though if you didn't had the message, or since it seems the cropping failed. By the way nice anonymization of content ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCapturerDownload.htm) if you want to get a screenshot of a scrolling window or anything with scroll bars. Use the Capture Scrolling Window `<Ctrl + Alt + PrtSc>` in manual mode.

Comment: As I said, these softwares/extensions only work with the main page scroll bar, not with the scroll in the div. I already tried.

Comment: Use the manual mode. I've already tried it, click the Capture Scrolling Window, while pressing Ctrl, select and draw the area you wanted to capture, then start clicking the scroll bar to capture the entire div.

Comment: It worked! Wow, impressive! I tried too many things, brother... I had lost all  hope, hehe. Thanks :D